# $-\frac76=-\frac {4n}{3}$ struggling on solving this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I was wondering how to do this equation step by step. I forgot how to but it would be awesome if someone could help me out
$$-\frac76=-\frac {4n}{3}$$

Comment: If you are solving for $n$, cross multiple.

Comment: Cross multiplying is a good start.  Or multiply each side by the expressions that are in the denominators of the fractions.

Comment: Please clarify - is $n$ in the numerator or denominator?

Comment: I'm trying to solve for n so it's not in numerator or denominator. I'l try cross multiply

Comment: @MK You are either multiplying by $n$ or dividing by $n$ - the title and the text of your question are currently ambiguous. Is it $-n\cdot \frac 43$ or $-\frac 4{3n}$?

Comment: I'm thing it's dividing because the answer for it is 7/8 sorry for the confusion

Comment: $\frac{-4}{3n}$ or $\frac{-4}{3}n$

Comment: the second one turkeyhundt

Comment: I hope my edit is correct?

Comment: @MarkBennet: You forget to change the title. Now fixed.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm pretty sure it's division if there was some way I could get my answer 7/8

Comment: @MK: Is it fine now?

Comment: @krish I believe it is $\frac{-4}{3}n$

Comment: Yes thank you everyone!

Comment: @Krish Happy you changed the title. Formatting in titles doesn't help searching. So "How do I simplify an algebraic fraction?" might be better than having the specific equation in the title. Then other people looking for the cross-multiplying technique might find it more easily.

Comment: @turkeyhundt: Look at 0P's last comment. I got confused. But from the accepted answer I realized that OP wants $n$ to be in numerator.

Comment: @Krish yeah, i think there were multiple conversations going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-\frac76=-\frac {4n}{3} $$

$$\frac{-7}{6} \times \frac{-3}4 = \frac{-4n}{3} \times \frac{-3}4$$

$$\frac{21 }{24} = n$$

$$ n = \frac{7}{8} $$

Answer (score 3):

Consider 
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}n
$$
where $b,d\neq 0$. Then
$$
n=\frac{ad}{bc}.
$$
Now if you have, 
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{dn}
$$
Then
$$
n=\frac{cb}{da}
$$
Both results were obtained by cross multiplying in order to isolate the unknown variable $n$

Comment: nice touch to put all the possible cases (as it's not clear from the question). +1 :)

Comment: @Krish I figure it couldn't hurt and would cover all the basis. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{-7}{6}=\frac{-4}{3}n\\3\times\frac{-7}{6}=-4\times n\\3\times -7=-4\times6\times n\\\frac{3\times -7}{-4\times 6}=n\\n=\frac{21}{24}=\frac{7}{8}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's the same sort of question as "How many dimes are ther in seven nickels?". To answer it, just convert everything to a common denomination--or, in this case, make the fractions being compared have the same denominator.

$$-\frac 76 =-\frac{4n}{3}$$
$$\frac {-7}6 = \frac{-4n}{3}$$
$$\frac {-7}6 = \frac{-4n\cdot 2}{3\cdot 2}$$
$$\frac {-7}6 = \frac{-8n}{6}$$

So it must be that $-7$ and $-8n$ are the same thing:
$$-7=-8n$$
$$n=\frac{-7}{-8}$$
$$n=\boxed{\dfrac 78}$$

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are way too complicated. You have:
$$-\frac76=-\frac {4n}{3}$$
Therefore:
$$\frac76=\frac {4n}{3}$$
Equivalently:
$$\frac76=\frac {8n}{6}$$
So:
$$7=8n$$
Thus:
$$n = \frac 7 8$$

Comment: This is way too complicated. Oh, wait--it's exactly the same as the other answers. Uh...

Comment: All other answers explicitly involve crossmultiplying. Mine does not.